# About the closedness of a certain product of two closed operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $S∈B(H)$ and let $T$ be a densely defined closed operator such that $TS\subset ST$. Assume further that $T$ is boundedly invertible.

Is it true that $ST$ is closed?

In my problem, $S$ and $T$ are both self adjoint and positive.

Comment: What does boundedly invertible mean? $T: D(T) \to H$ is injective and $T^{-1}: T(D(T)) \to H$ is bounded?

Comment: Are you also sure that you don't mean $ST \subseteq TS$?

Comment: Yes. It is not the usual commutativity...

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions?